# PowerShell hex to string conversion

Tags: powershell

Need help to convert all hex characters contained in a text file to string or ASCII. Hex characters appear in a standard format of

```
user1 domain1 7374726f6e6770617373776f7264403130                                               
user2 domain2 7374726f6e6770617373776f7264403120
```

After conversion it should show as

```
user1 domain1 strongpassword@10
```

the text file contains the multiple passwords, all arranged in a row

Comment: This may not work cross platform, but executes in windows with fewer lines of code

$h = "7374726f6e6770617373776f7264403130"
[Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001.SoapHexBinary]::Parse($h).Value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Get-Content file.txt | Foreach-Object{

    $user,$domain,$pass = $_.Split()

    $pass = for($i=0; $i -lt $pass.length; $i+=2)
    {
       [char][int]::Parse($pass.substring($i,2),'HexNumber')
    }

    $user,$domain,(-join $pass) -join ' '
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
$h =  7374726f6e6770617373776f7264403130

-join ($h -split '(..)' | ? { $_ } | % { [char][convert]::ToUInt32($_,16) })
```

Comment: the text file contains the multiple passwords, all arranged in a row, so we cannot define a variable like this I suppose

Answer (score 1):

How about this as an example of how to do it:

```
$text = 'user1 domain1 7374726f6e6770617373776f7264403130'
$p = [Regex]::Match($text, '\w+$').Value
$pass = ((0..(($p.length - 1) / 2) | % {[Char]([Convert]::toint16($p.SubString($_ * 2, 2), 16))}) -Join '')
$text = $text -Replace '\w+$', $pass
$text
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$pass=""
$t="7374726f6e6770617373776f7264403130"
$t -split '(.{2})' |%{ if ($_ -ne "") { $pass+=[CHAR]([CONVERT]::toint16("$_",16))  }}
write host $pass
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$IN="SOME LONG CRAZY STRING TO CONVERT TO HEX"

$HEX = $(($IN | Format-Hex).ToString().Split("`n")).ForEach({ $_.remove(0,11) -replace '[ ]{2,}.*$','' }).Split() -join ''

Write-Host $HEX

$OUT = $($HEX -split '(.{2})').ForEach({ if ($_ -ne "") { [CHAR]([CONVERT]::toint16("$_",16)) } }) -join ''

Write-Host $OUT
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)

Comment: Apparently my lack of explanation offended someone. This converts a string of text **$IN** to hex using **Format-Hex** it then parses and joins the output so your result is a single string of hexidecimal values **$HEX**. Then I convert the Hexidecimal string **$HEX** back to text **$OUT**.

Answer (score 0):

The first response was the only one that returned the line with the user, domain, *and* password hex-decoded.

The second response was the most Perl-like in elegance.

Here's a combination of the two:

```
[regex]$regEx = '(\S+)$';
$scriptBlock = { param ($match); -join ( $match.Groups[1].Value -split '(..)' | ? { $_; } | % { [Char]( [Convert]::ToInt16($_, 16) ); } ); }
Get-Content file.txt | % { $regEx.Replace($_, $scriptBlock); }
```

The scriptblock can be formatted for readability instead of brevity / Perl-like obfuscation. :)

```
$scriptBlock = { 
    param ($match); 
    -join ( 
        $match.Groups[1].Value -split '(..)' | ? { $_; } | % { 
            [Char]( [Convert]::ToInt16($_, 16) ); 
        } 
    ); 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative. This has the virtue of giving you an object that can be viewed using Format-Table or exported using Export-Csv. Also, the ConvertForm-Hexadecimal implementation here is very fast and works well even with very large strings.

```
function ConvertFrom-Hexadecimal([string] $hexString)
{
    [byte[]] $data = @()

    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($hexString) -eq $true -or $hexString.Length % 2 -ne 0)
    {
        throw New-Object FormatException("Hexadecimal string must not be empty and must contain an even number of digits to be valid.");
    }

    $hexString = $hexString.ToUpperInvariant()
    $data = New-Object byte[] -ArgumentList ($hexString.Length / 2)

    for ([int] $index = 0; $index -lt $hexString.Length; $index += 2)
    {
        [int] $highDigitValue = if ($hexString[$index] -le ([char] '9')) { $hexString[$index] - ([char] '0') } else { $hexString[$index] - ([char] 'A') + 10 }
        [int] $lowDigitValue = if ($hexString[$index + 1] -le ([char] '9')) { $hexString[$index + 1] - ([char] '0') } else { $hexString[$index + 1] - ([char] 'A') + 10 }

        if ($highDigitValue -lt 0 -or $lowDigitValue -lt 0 -or $highDigitValue -gt 15 -or $lowDigitValue -gt 15)
        {
            throw New-Object FormatException("An invalid digit was encountered. Valid hexadecimal digits are 0-9 and A-F.")
        }
        else
        {
            [byte] $value = [byte](($highDigitValue -shl 4) -bor ($lowDigitValue -band 0x0F))
            $data[$index / 2] = $value;
        }
    }

    return ,$data
}

$fileName = '.\testfile.txt'

$passwordColumn = @{ name = 'Password'; expression = { $bytes = ConvertFrom-Hexadecimal $_.EncodedPassword; [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($bytes); } }
$users = Import-Csv -Delimiter ' ' -Header User, Domain, EncodedPassword -Path $fileName | Select *, $passwordColumn
$users | ft -AutoSize
```