# In Windows, how can I restore original characters to a csv file that have been replaced with hex ASCII?

Tags: windows, powershell, csv, hex, ascii

I have a csv file that contains names Like O'Brien that appear as O%27Brien or St. Something that appear as St%2ESomething.  I don't have access to generate a new csv of this data, and I need the names in a correct format because I'm writing a PowerShell script to search for the names on another server.

I tried implementing something similar to the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229866/powershell-hex-to-string-conversion) but I can't get it to work for the problem I'm experiencing.

It doesn't matter to me if the solution is in PowerShell as long as I can run it on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Uri.UnescapeDataString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.uri.unescapedatastring) method which you can call from powershell like this:

```
# > [Uri]::UnescapeDataString("O%27Brien")
O'Brien
```