# Powershell: convert UTF-8 binary code to image

Tags: powershell, binary-image

I have a UTF8 binary encoded image and I want to convert it to png with powershell. I found the following:

```
$bytes = [Convert]::FromBase64String($base64)
[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("imagen.png", $bytes)
```

But this deals with base64 encodings. It's not what I want. Is there a way to do it in powershell?

Thank you!

Comment: What does "UTF8 binary encoded image" mean? UTF-8 is a _text_ encoding. Is some text encoded? What is the underlying image format? If it's not PNG, then performing the image conversion will likely be easiest with some external tool, like [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/)

Comment: Actually I have a database with png images encoded in binary UTF8 text and my intention is to convert them back to png images to save them in folders.

Comment: @Raulus can you put here an example of "binary UTF8 text" with image? Or at least a code on other language which puts image to your database, for example

Comment: I do not have to code that was made to convert the images into text but I attach an example:

```

Comment: ```
0x2F396A2F34414151536B5A4A5267414241514141415141424141442F32774244414149424151454241514942415145434167494341675144416749434167554542414D4542675547426759464267594742776B494267634A427759474341734943516F4B43676F4B4267674C4441734B44416B4B4367722F327742444151494341674943416755444177554B4277594843676F4B43676F4B43676F4B43676F4B43676F4B436
```


and on ...

Comment: There are 65535 characters

Comment: @Raulus it looks like Hexadecimal representation, so you need something like that function https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MSIdentityTools/1.0.0.3/Content/ConvertFrom-HexString.ps1 and you have this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229866/powershell-hex-to-string-conversion

Comment: it's very big and it won't let me upload it.

Comment: Whatever your program did to encode the original file, it *isn’t* a simple hex string of a PNG file’s bytes. According to Wikipedia, the first 8 bytes of a PNG would be ```0x89504E470D0A1A0A``` - see the File Format section of https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics

Comment: I'm going to look for the code to see how they converted it.